# citrix not working in Arch Linux - libraries error

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have a citrix ica file that I need to open. 
I set the default application as wfica.

I am using Arch Linux and the citrix thing worked until yesterday before setting the custom command line. It automatically worked with citrix. But, I was playing with the linux and I wanted to remove unwanted/unused packages and I typed

`sudo pacman -Rsn $(pacman -Qqdt)`

A bunch of packages got removed and I think that is why this citrix is not working properly.

After that I also did a 
`sudo pacman -Syu` 
to update all the packages but in-vain.

EDIT:

```
[srikanth@myhost linuxx86]$ sh wfica.sh 
/home/srikanth/ICAClient/linuxx86/wfica: error while loading shared libraries: libXaw.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[srikanth@myhost linuxx86]$ pwd
/home/srikanth/ICAClient/linuxx86
[srikanth@myhost linuxx86]$ whereis libXaw
libXaw: /usr/lib/libXaw7.so /usr/lib/libXaw.so /usr/lib/libXaw6.so
```

Looks like there is some error while loading libraries

EDIT:

@Kevin: still the same.

```
[srikanth@myhost linuxx86]$ cd /usr/lib
[srikanth@myhost lib]$ sudo ln -s libXaw7.so libXaw.so.7
ln: failed to create symbolic link `libXaw.so.7': File exists
[srikanth@myhost lib]$ pwd
/usr/lib
[srikanth@myhost lib]$ cd ~/ICAClient/linuxx86/
[srikanth@myhost linuxx86]$ ls
CHARICONV.DLL  eula.txt  install.txt  libctxssl.so  Npica     PDCRYPT1.DLL  readme.txt  util         VDSPMIKE.DLL  wfica_assoc.sh
config         help      keyboard     NDS.DLL       Npica.ad  PDCRYPT2.DLL  setupwfc    VDEUEM.DLL   wfcmgr        wfica.sh
desktop        icons     keystore     nls           npica.so  pkginf        TW1.DLL     VDSCARD.DLL  wfica
[srikanth@myhost linuxx86]$ sudo ldconfig
[srikanth@myhost linuxx86]$ sh wfica.sh 
/home/srikanth/ICAClient/linuxx86/wfica: error while loading shared libraries: libXaw.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[srikanth@myhost linuxx86]$ cd /usr/lib
[srikanth@myhost lib]$ ls -ltr libXaw7*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 462536 Jan 19  2011 libXaw7.so.7.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jan 19  2011 libXaw7.so.7 -> libXaw7.so.7.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jan 19  2011 libXaw7.so -> libXaw7.so.7.0.0
[srikanth@myhost lib]$
```

Comment: How did you set it in the first place, and why do you think you need to clear it?

Comment: I right clicked the file and clicked on open with and there are two tabs, installed application and custom command line. I went to command line and I typed wfica. 
I am not sure why I need to clear it as a matter of fact, The file is not opening properly.

Comment: It sounds like a library alias may have been lost somehow. Try `sudo ln -s libXaw7.so /usr/lib/libXaw.so.7`.  You may then have to do `sudo ldconfig` to make sure the runtime loader finds it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on 64-bit Linux and wfica is a 32-bit application. If that's really the case, then installing [lib32-libxaw](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=20894) should fix it.

Comment: awesome, thanks. That is exactly the problem.